# Exasol: Tables or logs where queries executed using an application/reporting server server

Tags: sql, exasolution

I have a reporting application connected to exasol server where queries are executing on that exasol server. I need the logs or tables where i can find the queries executed while I completed the execution of report.

Note: I am looking for tables/ logs where we have history of SQL queries executed in exasol server

Answer (score 2):

System tables `EXA_DBA_AUDIT_SQL` and `EXA_DBA_AUDIT_SESSIONS` contain the information you're looking for. But please note that "Auditing" flag has to be enabled. You may check it in ExaOperation on the database settings screen. Changing this flag requires database restart.

Hope it helps.